# How can I get the file type from an online uri?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I want to use Boring Avatars but rendering in the frontend could either be an image or svg. I wanted to get the file type from the Boring Avatar's online uri but the example below doesn't have an svg file extension in the end.

```
https://source.boringavatars.com/marble/120/Maria%20Mitchell?colors=264653,2a9d8f,e9c46a,f4a261,e76f51
```

Reference: https://github.com/boringdesigners/boring-avatars

Comment: It's not from the url itself, but you could look at the response header `content-type`. Is that an option?

Comment: If there's a [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) response header present, you should extract the filetype from there. Otherwise look at the [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header

Comment: Okay will check both of those. Thanks!